# Basic Python BeautifulSoup web-scraping Tripadvisor reviews and data cleaning

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-cleaning

I'm a complete beginner at programming and to StackOverflow and I just need to do some basic web-scraping from a TripAdvisor page and clean some useful information from it. Display it nicely etc. I'm trying to isolate the title of the cafe, the number of ratings and the rating itself. I'm thinking I might need to convert it to text and use regex or something? I really don't know. An example of what I mean would be:

Output:

Coffee Cafe, 4 out of 5 bubbles, 201 reviews.

Something like that. I will put my code so far below, any help I could get would amazing and I would be infinitely grateful. Cheers.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_HTML(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    return html


Tripadvisor_reviews_HTML=get_HTML(
'https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Restaurants- 
 g255068-c8-Brisbane_Brisbane_Region_Queensland.html')


def get_review_count(HTML):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(Tripadvisor_reviews_HTML, "lxml")
    for element in soup(attrs={'class' : 'reviewCount'}):
        print(element)

get_review_count(Tripadvisor_reviews_HTML)

def get_review_score(HTML):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(Tripadvisor_reviews_HTML, "lxml")
    for four_point_five_score in soup(attrs={'alt' : '4.5 of 5 bubbles'}):
        print(four_point_five_score)


get_review_score(Tripadvisor_reviews_HTML)

def get_cafe_name(HTML):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(Tripadvisor_reviews_HTML, "lxml")
    for name in soup(attrs={'class' : "property_title"}):
        print(name)



get_cafe_name(Tripadvisor_reviews_HTML)
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code?

Comment: As far as I know, nothing. I just can't figure out how to clean/ isolate the title, review score and review count from the big messy chunk of HTML. How would I go about it? 

Convert it to text file somehow and use regex? I'm just stuck, I've looked everywhere trying to find some examples of how to proceed, but no luck so far...

Comment: Well, what does the code do right now? What does it print? Is it not what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to use `.text` in every print statement. However, try the below approach to get all the three fields from that site.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

URL = "https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Restaurants-g255068-c8-Brisbane_Brisbane_Region_Queensland.html"

def get_info(link):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(),"lxml")
    for items in soup.find_all(class_="shortSellDetails"):
        name = items.find(class_="property_title").get_text(strip=True)
        bubble = items.find(class_="ui_bubble_rating").get("alt")
        review = items.find(class_="reviewCount").get_text(strip=True)
        print(name,bubble,review)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_info(URL)
```

Result you may get like:

```
Double Shot New Farm 4.5 of 5 bubbles 218 reviews
Goodness Gracious Cafe 4.5 of 5 bubbles 150 reviews
New Farm Deli & Cafe 4.5 of 5 bubbles 273 reviews
Coffee Anthology 4.5 of 5 bubbles 116 reviews
```

Comment: Don't forget to leave here a feedback when you are done running the above script @noob123.

Comment: Wow thank you! That worked perfectly! Any ideas though on how I  could take this output and display in some sort of table?

Comment: Would you know a way to print all possible accessible fields in `items`?